# CC_SYNTHESIZE(int, beadColor, _BeadColor); Invalid use of 'this' outside of a non-static member function

Tags: c++, cocos2d-iphone

I have some issues in my cocos2d-x code.
I post my code at here.

BeadSprite.h

```
#include "cocos2d.h"
#include "iSet.h"
#include "LHSprite.h"

enum{
    BlueBead = 1,
    RedBead = 2,
    GreenBead = 3,
    WhiteBead = 4,
    BlackBead = 5,
    HeartBead = 6,
    StrongBlueBead = 7,
    StrongRedBead = 8,
    StrongGreenBead = 9,
    StrongWhiteBead = 10,
    StrongBlackBead = 11,
    StrongHeartBead = 12,
    ClearBead = 13,
};

USING_NS_CC;

class BeadSprite : public LHSprite
{
private:

    void changeBeadColorAction(int ToColor);
    void changeBeadColor(int ToColor);
    void boombBeads(int ToColor);
    void boombStrongBeads(int ToColor);
    void boombStrongFX();
    void runShatterEffectWithCan(CCDelayTime* time);
public:
    /*static LHSprite* spriteWithName(const std::string& spriteName,
                                    const std::string& sheetName,
                                    const std::string& spriteHelperFile);*/
    CC_SYNTHESIZE(int, beadColor, _BeadColor);
};

#endif
```

BeadSprite.cpp

```
#include "BeadSprite.h"
using namespace cocos2d;

void FsetBeadColor(const std::string& color){
    if(color == "BlueBead") this->beadColor = BlueBead; <-Invalid use of 'this' outside of a non-static member function
    if(color == "RedBead") this->beadColor = RedBead; <-Invalid use of 'this' outside of a non-static member function
    if(color == "GreenBead") this->beadColor = GreenBead; <-Invalid use of 'this' outside of a non-static member function
    if(color == "WhiteBead") this->beadColor = WhiteBead; <-Invalid use of 'this' outside of a non-static member function
    if(color == "BlackBead") this->beadColor = BlackBead; <-Invalid use of 'this' outside of a non-static member function
    if(color == "HeartBead") this->beadColor = HeartBead; <-Invalid use of 'this' outside of a non-static member function
}

void changeBeadColorAction(int ToColor){

}
```

error:
BeadSprite.cpp:31:29: Invalid use of 'this' outside of a non-static member function

How to fix this bug? please :(
this use cocos2d-x-2.2.1

Comment: What do you expect this to be pointing to?

Comment: That phrase "'this' outside of a non-static member function" is plain stupid - FsetBeadColor is a freestanding function not connected to any class (give your compiler a slap for that phrase)

Comment: @DieterLücking: Well, `this` is only valid inside of a non-static member function, so using `this` outside of that context is an error.  So the error is technically correct...  It reminds me of the old GCC undefined variable message:  "First use this function."  They improved that to "First use _in_ this function," to disambiguate the word "use".

Comment: @JoeZ Yep, technically, but mind twisting

Comment: @DieterLücking: That's why I compared it to GCC's old mind-twisting error.  The first several times I saw it I thought to myself "But that's a variable, not a function, and I _am_ using it!"  And then, for the next few years helping classmates, I had to explain the same thing to them...  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your use of `CC_SYNTHESIZE` will create a private member `beadColor` and public getter `get_BeadColor` and setter `set_BeadColor`. So your function implementation has the wrong name and needs to be qualified as belonging to the class `BeadSprite`:

```
void BeadSprite::set_BeadColor(const std::string& color) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: And once they make that fix, they can delete all the unnecessary `this->` in the method.

Comment: I try to delet `this->` but it is not fix bug.

Comment: @user3111438 Did you do everything else?